# how can I debug client side javascript (in html pages) in google appscripts

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-apps-script

I am starting to appreciate the debugging features in the google app script editing environment, however I notice that I don't seem to be able to select client side javascript functions to debug in html pages, as shown in this image[image: unable to select javascript functions in html pages in google app script editing environment]

Is there any way round this?  At the moment I guess I'm just going to hack and watch error messages ...

Comment: oh, yes, and I know I can use the chrome debugging environment - maybe that's the only way to go for client side javascript ...

Comment: ah, hmm, but then the client side script is all rewritten so that's not so good ...

Comment: I wish there was an active google app script irc or skype chat room, the ones here seem dead: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-script/ZF0F_3pFtGM

Comment: and this doesn't help: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service?hl=en#DebuggingTemplates

Comment: They really ought to emblazen a warning about this atop the Google scripts home page to forewarn prospective adopters of this impending peril. And that you can't embed a script-produced page inside anything or make an asynchronous call to the same script because of cross site limitations and how the page is served in the cloud.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, there is no other good way to debug client side web UI other than with console logs. As you noted the JavaScript/DOM is re-written so you can't use standard Chrome debug tools.

Comment: is there a way to disable (for dev purpose) the Caja sanitization & minification process so that we can at least see where our code fails instead of dummy userCodeAppPanel references to null code ?

Comment: I think it is Closure now instead of Caja...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can embed alerts in the javascript in your HTML page served from Google app script but sometimes the alerts do not show up. I have no idea why. When they work they are great. I have never seen any output from Logger.log or console.log statements inside the javascript.