# Can I prevent obfuscation when debugging my Google Apps Script spreadsheet add-on?

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, obfuscation, add-on

I am writing and debugging a Google Spreadsheet add-on in JavaScript with the Google Apps Script platform. The code is currently bound to a spreadsheet, and I access it through menu items I add to the spread. I am sometimes able use the debugger available as part of the developer tools in Chrome to step through my code. At other times, my code is obfuscated and un-debuggable. Today, there was a chance from unobfuscated to obfuscated code in the same session, without my having changed anything.

Is there a way to prevent my unpublished add-on code from being obfuscated for ease of debugging?

Comment: Are you looking to debug client-side code? What are the steps that you are following to use the Chrome devTools debugger?

Comment: Yes, I want to debug the code client-side. I am opening the debugger in Chrime by selecting More Tools > Developer Tools.

Comment: Related questions : https://stackoverflow.com/q/26518902/1595451, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46520959/1595451

Comment: @Rubén Thank you, the second link is relevant, although I still don't know why sometimes the code is unobfuscated (which lets me debug as shown in the first link) and sometimes it isn't.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] ( include code and the steps that you have followed to debug the code and got obfuscated code)